# Is it permissible to buy clothes you really like but don't need, while also doing some sadqah and being thankful to Allah

Tags: quran, hadith

I am a working woman. This has happened to me a couple of times.

I sometimes find very beautiful clothes and I buy them, even when I don't necessarily need them; and since I am overweight, so I look fat in whatever I wear. But those clothes look so pretty and I buy them. They are *not* overly expensive clothes. They are normal in price range and will be useful if I stay in the country. However, I may be deciding to apply for higher studies abroad in colder countries (even though it will take at least a year even if it happens), so these clothes won't work there.

Those clothes have served me in the sense that when family friends (not non-mahram) visit us or meet me in social gatherings, they find me well-dressed, decently dressed, well behaved etc. (alhamdoliAllah), and have mentioned that here and there (alhamdoliAllah and mashaAllah), even in contexts of marriage proposals.

On the other hand, my savings account has very little money, so what will I do if Godforbid I get sick and can not afford treatment. But I give in to my temptation and buy clothes etc.

When I buy somethings like this, I also do a little bit of sadqah (may Allah accept. Ameen).

I also suffer from anxiety and Attention Deficit Disorder, so shaitan puts doubts in my mind in every aspect of my life.

So I want to know if I am committing a sin or is shaitan unnecessarily trying to make me confused, unhappy etc. and distract me from ibadah and what truly matters. Please guide me in light of Quran and authentic hadith.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allah says in the Quran:

> It is He who created for you all of that which is on the earth. (2:29)

> O children of Adam, We have bestowed upon you clothing to conceal your private parts and as adornment. But the clothing of righteousness - that is best. That is from the signs of Allah that perhaps they will remember. (7:26)

> O children of Adam, take your adornment at every masjid, and eat and drink, but be not excessive. Indeed, He likes not those who commit excess. (7:31)

> Say, "Who has forbidden the adornment of Allah which He has produced for His servants and the good [lawful] things of provision?" Say, "They are for those who believe during the worldly life [but] exclusively for them on the Day of Resurrection." Thus do We detail the verses for a people who know. (7:32)

In essence, food, drink, clothes, and all the adornments of this world are halal in general until some specific evidence is found to prohibit them.

There is no limitation that we only eat as much as we need (although this is recommended; there are many ahadith about the recommendation of eating less) or that we only buy clothes as much as we need.

Rather, it is allowed to buy good clothes as long as that is not worn in any haram ways. For women, they shouldn't wear clothes that are meant to be attractive or show any awrah (any part of their body other than face and hands) in public or in front of men.